# PHP, Return value from Array

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to return the value from a MySql table and seem to be able to get everything except what I need!

PHP:

```
<?php
session_start();
include('config.php');
$user_check=$_SESSION['login_user'];

$sql_rec = "select UserID from useradmin where username='$user_check' ";
$rs_rec = mysql_query($sql_rec);
$data_rec = mysql_fetch_object($rs_rec);

$userID = $data_rec->UserID; 

$sql_fn = "select * from Candidates where UserID='$userID' ";
$rs_fn = mysql_query($sql_fn);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($rs_fn);
$data_fn = $row['contactno'];

print $sql_fn;
print $data_fn;
print $row;

?>
```

$sql_fn is giving me the right result

$row is giving me 'Array'

but $data_fn is giving me nothing.

Essentially I'm trying to populate a text field with the result like this:

HTML:

```
<label for="contactno">Contact Number</label> <br> <input type="test" name="contactno" id="contactno" class="input_field" value="<?php echo $row['contactno'];?>">
```

Could someone point out where I've gone wrong please?

Thank you.

Comment: Add this line `var_dump($row);` and tell us what you get. Probably your column's name isn't `contactno`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need this:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($rs_fn, MYSQL_ASSOC);
```

And check your query with `mysql_num_rows($query) > 0` to ensure that it has returned data otherwise you're going to get error from `mysql_fetch_*`.

BTW, mysql functions are deprecated. Use mysqli or PDO or pg.

Comment: I've made this change, however `$data_fn;` still seems to be returning nothing, unfortunately? I've done as @Joe T suggested and can see the array has what I want. I just can't get what I want out of it :)

Comment: @Mcam435 Well in this case it'll usually pop an error to you if that index does not exist or if it does, then you have nothing stored in that index.

Comment: Actually, it's working now after adding your code above, I'd just typed it out wrong. It's just the `<label for="contactno">Contact Number</label> <br> <input type="test" name="contactno" id="contactno" class="input_field" value="<?php echo $data_fn;?>"> ` that's not working now (however I do have it printing the results at the top of the page).

Comment: Turns out that's just a problem with the quotes stopping the code running. Can figure that bit out myself though. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Print the contents of your array with `print_r($row);` and that should show you what you've got.  (I Think MahanGM is right, you're expecting an associative array when you only got a plain numeric one)

More info about using print_r: http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php

PS: use [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php) for new development

Answer (score 0):

`_fetch_row` returns an indexed array. You want `_fetch_assoc` if you're accessing by column names.

Also, to output an array, use `var_dump`.

Answer (score 0):

$sql_fn = "select * from Candidates where UserID='$userID' ";
Hi there

How your UserID field is stored, is that integer type or string if it is a number then you would not need a single quote around it.
You will definitely get the $sql_fn because it is just simply a query string.
You need to check what in your return array.
Check if the contactno is the correct column name in your table. Just simply print_r($row)
then you can see the answer